# Xbox ONE Bluetooth controller won't pair anymore

Tags: bluetooth-pairing, game-controllers

I bought an Xbox One Bluetooth controller and it worked just fine. I tried to pair it again, but the controller turned off mid process and now a "Cant pair with Xbox Wireless Controller because of an incorrect PIN or passcode" dialog box appears.

I tried formatting the phone, removing the device, soft reset both phone and controller, booting on safe mode and booting to recovery and wiping cache data – but nothing of that worked; connecting it via OTG doesn't work either, it receives power but is not detected by the phone.

I'm using a Moto G 4 running Android 6.0.1. Any ideas on how to get that working again?

Comment: Did you use the "forget this device" function in the Bluetooth menu?

Comment: Yes, I already tried that

Comment: Did you update the xbox one controller? If so, Microsoft might have actually bricked this feature.

Comment: I thought the same, the weird thing is it pairs with any other android device, my phone is the only one that doesnt pairs anymore

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Upated through xbox app and now it stopped working..